# Arduino compiling error on werkstatt stem lesson (processing code)

Tags: arduino, processing

Trying to follow along with a moog stem project to view PWM using arduino and the code they provided isn’t compiling.  https://www.werkstattworkshop.com/education/lessons/vcosci2

When compiling the waveshape.pde file in the arduino IDE it throws an error on the code line “import cc.arduino.*;” that says:

exit status 1 ‘import’ does not name a type

As far as I can tell from the authors notes this line of code imports a library.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is not accepted to include a link or picture to your code. Please add your code as text so the next person can understand what your question+answer was even when the linked website is down. It is however useful to include a link to an external resource **in addition** to your example code.

Comment: Helpful information thanks Tarick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.pde files run in [Processing](https://processing.org/) on the PC/laptop.

It appears that this Processing sketch is written to run with a Arduino programmed with the [Firmata](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Firmata) software.

You need to

1. Install processing
2. Download Firmata and upload it to your Arduino
3. Run the .pde file in Processing.